# Remove cookie upon leaving the webpage

Tags: cookies, web

Is there a way to delete ALL cookies upon leaving the web application automatically ?

knowing that he can leave the web page by clicking on a link, closing tab, clicking on home page button, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cookie would save in client's machine, if you want to close cookie on close window you can set a [session cookie](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/cookie2.shtml), will automatically expire when session closed. but if you want to close cookie on close tab you can use javascript event on close tab such as window.onclose to delete all cookies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java set the age of the cookie=-1 this will make sure that the cookie is deleted when the browser closes. In case user is logging out by clicking on a link make cookie age=0 this will delete the cookie.have a look at

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html