# Making my website NOT leave cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I've done some research and all I can seem to find are ways to make a tracking cookie, and the closest I can find is here: [Remove cookie upon leaving the webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402493/remove-cookie-upon-leaving-the-webpage) . Now, this'll work, but I was hoping for a method that would kind of pre-empt the issue.

Is there any way to tell your website to not leave a cookie, whether through javascript or some other method?

Ps. My biggest reason for doing this is when I'm editing my website, I'm reloading the page over and over and over again, and oftentimes it stores the content for a little while and I have to open a new browser/go to another computer to see my new content.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websites don't procure cookies from the air. They only leave cookies if you specifically program them to do that, so whatever code you're using to set the cookie, just don't do that.

---

Are you possibly talking about the *cache* instead?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes I am. Thank you for helping me clarify that